# Is it possible to determine what jack on a switch a computer is connected to?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-connection

Is it possible to determine programmatically what jack on a network switch a computer is connected to?

Comment: I would read into how a switch words, the answer to this question is answered in that documentation, once you understand the hardware this software question is trivial. **Hint: The answer is of course not.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either possible or not possible, depending on the switch.

If it's a managed switch, you could query its management interface to determine the MAC addresses behind each port. Then you could match that up with the hardware address on the computer you're interested in.

Some switches have discovery protocols (such as [CDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) or [LLDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol)) which will broadcast the port's identity to whichever devices are attached. You could sniff the network for these packets to determine the port your computer is connected to.

Comment: +1: I've spoken to some resident experts here at my office.  It seems that the answer is that technically, it may be possible, but in a large organization where different locations use different hardware and security is important, it is not practical.

Comment: Yes, it would be difficult to come up with a general solution. For curiosity's sake, I would sniff your network using Wireshark and filter it for `lldp` and `cdp` to see if you see any of those discovery packets.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disonnecting them one by one and each time testing if the network connection goes down.

Comment: I want to do this programmatically if it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

To identify switch port connected to your pc ; you need to manually access the switch and remove ur rj-45 cable so you can visualize any port having state of disconnection.. dm gui can be used if switch is managable

> > cdp and lldp wont work for pc as it doesnt support it

Comment: No, this is not the answer because I am interested in determining this programatically, not by pulling out a connection and seeing what happens.